# Horizontal scroll bar not working even when I am setting a fixed width to my div parent?

Tags: html, css, sass, scrollbar

as the question mention, my horizontal scrollbar is not working, I am working on a react app, I am trying to build a small TableData component, here is my rendered jsx code :

```
<table>
        <div className="co-table">
                <div className="co-table__long">
                    <div className="co-table__header">
                        <div className="co-table__header--col">
                            {" "}
                            <span>Date d'operation</span>{" "}
                        </div>
                        <div className="co-table__header--col">
                            {" "}
                            <span>Type de Mouvement</span>{" "}
                        </div>
                        <div className="co-table__header--col">
                            {" "}
                            <span>Montant ($$) </span>{" "}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="co-table__corps">
                        <div className="co-table__corps--head">head</div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="co-table__corps">
                        <div className="co-table__corps--head">head</div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="co-table__corps">
                        <div className="co-table__corps--head">head</div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="co-table__corps--row">
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                            <div className="co-table__corps--column">ff</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</table>
```

I know it is so much code but it is repeated code, I will explain in details what I want to achieve, here is my SASS file :

```
.co-table {
width:300px;
height: 150px;


&__long {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    &:after {
        content: "";
        clear: both;
    }
}

&__header {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height: 150px;
    float: left;

    &--col {
        width:100px;
        height: 50px;
        background: #333;
        color:white;
        span {
            font-size:13px;
            padding:10px 0;
        }
    }
}


&__corps {
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    height: 150px;
    &--head {
        width:60px;
        height: 150px;
        background:lightgray;
        float: left;

    }
    &--row {
        float: left;
        width:100px;
        height: 150px;
    }
    &--column {
        width:100px;
        height: 50px;
        border:1px solid lightblue;
    }
}

&:after {
    content: "";
    clear:both;
}


}
```

As you can see in my SASS file I am trying to add the horizontal scrollbar to the div with **** co-table__long **** class but it is not working, that div had its children and their total width is more than 700px, and I fixed my parent width to 300 px so I can see the horizontal scrollbar .. instead I see the vertical one, I see also the horizontal one but not working ..

Here is what I am looking for : [image]

Here is a link to my work, I hope it will work :

https://codesandbox.io/s/y03696lrl9

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you throw together a live example on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new)?

Comment: @AndyHoffman Done

Answer (score 0):

change your css for "co-table__long" from this:

```
.co-table__long {    
    height: 150px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

into this:

```
.co-table__long {    
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

you need to have 'width/max-width' set in the element on which you are using 'overflow'

[check this codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/94p80o0k4o?fontsize=14)

Comment: That is not the solution, I want something like the last image you ll see in my edited Post. Thank you for your help Sir.

Comment: you asked to have scrollbar in "co-table__long" div. whatever, to achieve something like your new image you'll have to change your markup a little. you need to wrap your "co-table__corps" divs with another div. and then adjust the css accordingly. you better use flexbox to flow items horizontally. check this [new codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jnjy5ol20y) . Hope it helps